# how can find list of the sites connecting to the app pool using appcmd.exe

Tags: iis, powershell, windows-command-prompt, microsoft, appcmd

I can see a list of site and list of app pool separately.

but how can I find wich site using from the app pool.

e.g:

we have an app pool with name: app1

i want to send command to find how sites connecting to the app1.

Comment: `AppCmd.exe list APP`? Please note that SF isn't an education center… nor a free script writing service!

Comment: @JosefZ AppCmd.exe list APP taking the list all apps. but i have a app with name "app1" and i want a command to get list of site using the "app1"